# Seleniumwebdirver with Java- Login authentication failing ; passing correct credentials

Tags: javascript, java, authentication, selenium-webdriver, login-page

I am trying hands-on for login page
Passing valid credentials using automation code, still system is giving error:

> Login Failed.

Language: Selenium webdriver with Java on Eclipse.

I have tried standard way:

```
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.className("flex-signup"));
Login.click();
WebElement EmailAdd = driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress")); 

WebElement EmailAdd = Driver.findElement(By.id("****"));
EmailAdd.sendKeys("************");
WebElement Passwd = driver.findElement(By.id("****"));
Passwd.sendKeys("*******");
```

I also used alternate way, JavaScript driver. But this also not working on the application.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='*************';" ,****);
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('****').value='**********';");
WebElement BLogin = driver.findElement(By.className("ladda-label"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", BLogin);
```

Application is in JavaScript so, I used JavaScript driver also, but same output.

Comment: Reason for `Login Failed.`? Error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add explicit wait in your code i.e. enter the text in the field only when it is visible. Give a try to following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.className("flex-signup"));
Login.click();
//WebElement EmailAdd = driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddress")); 
//WebElement EmailAdd = Driver.findElement(By.id("****"));
WebElement EmailAdd=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("****"));

EmailAdd.sendKeys("************");

WebElement Passwd = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("****"));
Passwd.sendKeys("*******");
```

and then click on `Login` button

Answer (score 0):

Try for different browsers like Firefox, chrome and opera.

- WebDriver firefox=new FirefoxDriver() //for firefox
- WebDriver chrome=new ChromeDriver();//for chrome.

Try and see.

Comment: i m running on chrome. and i tried geko and ie thing already.
I don't think it is related to the browser here. because in chrome the code is running till end only on clicking on Login. results are: login failed.
Correct me if i am wrong.
I am new to coding world.

Answer (score 0):

What happens after Login.click is performed?
If login form requires some time to be rendered(even 30 milliseconds may be important), then you should put a wait! otherwise driver will instantly try to sendkeys credentials(even if login form isn't ready for getting input data yet), so some of the first symbols may be lost.

P.S. i know i could make some major grammar mistakes, sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you Daniil. Yeah i used the explicit time wait . but that is also not helping. Anyways thank you. i am no longer able to access the website link. so i can't try other any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting a step in the login process.

Below is the way I think most login processes look.

1. Find ID Box and send Keys
2. Find PW Box and send Keys
3. Find Login Button and Click / send "Enter Key" with PW send Keys.

Yours looks like this.

1. Click Login(?)
2. Find WebElement EmailAdd
3. Find WebElement EmailAdd (x2) (Using different driver call)
4. Send Keys to EmailAdd
5. Find WebElement Passwd
6. Send Keys to Passwd

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
The steps are correct. I have to first click on Login option and then i have to enter the credentials. that's why first line of code is for Login.  Yeah true i am using 2 different driver cal for web element email id. i removed one now.  but after rectifying that also the problem is not solved.  Anyways thank you.